# Existence of holomorphic $h(z)$ such that $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ when $g(z) \neq 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**

Let $f$ and $g$ be holomorphic and suppose $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|$ on some open disk $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$. Assuming $g \not\equiv 0$, prove that there exists a holomorphic function $h: z \rightarrow h(z)$ defined on the whole disk $\Omega$ such that $$h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$$ at every $z \in \Omega$ where $g(z) \neq 0$.

**Attempt**

I think I have to define $$h(z)=\begin{cases} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} \ &g(z) \neq 0\\ \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} \ &g(z_0)=0 \end{cases}$$ and show that $z_0$ is a removable discontinuity by showing that $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} $ remains bounded. Can I use the assumption along with continuity of $f$ and $g$ to claim that since $\left|\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right|\leq 1$ in a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$, $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}\left|\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right|\leq 1$ and thus $z_0$ is a removable discontinuity and consequently $h$ can be made analytic at $z_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct except at one point: you do not know *a priori* that if $g(z_0)=0$ then
$$
\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}
$$
exists. You know that $f/g$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $z_0$ an that $f/g$ is bounded. This implies that the limit exists.

In short, you need to change the order in the argument.

Comment: do you mean $f/g$ at the end instead of $f/z$?

Comment: Yes, of course. I will edit.